# Which way up does capillary matting go?

Tags: watering, greenhouse

I have purchased some capillary matting to aid with watering in my greenhouse. It is the first time that I have used such a product and I have a rather novice question as a result. Which way up should I be placing the capillary matting on my surface?

The matting in question has a white fence fluffy side and a blue-green mesh like membrane side.

[image: Blue Green and White Sides of the Capillary Matting]

The instructions go over the basic setup but do not suggests which way up I should place the matting.

[image: Included Instructions on Setting Up Capillary Watering Mat]

This question extends to the tail which is placed in the water reservoir. Should it be placed with the sides matching that of the main matt or should it be placed with a certain side up?

I have put a waterproof layer of plastic under the mat. If I find it drying out rapidly or my greenhouse becomes too humid, I'll put a layer of gravel or plastic ontop of the watering mat too.

Answer (score 2):

Usually white side down, but with most, you can use them either side down - the white side reflects more light and should help with ripening the fruits on any fruiting plants you're growing later on, whereas the coloured side is intended to help with warming if used during colder weather. I've never seen one with a mid blue coloured side - they're usually grey, pale grey or green, but I know blue coloured ones do exist. It's probably sensible to contact the manufacturer of this particular matting just to be sure.

UPDATE: I just noticed where you are - ask the B & Q staff to find out and let you know (if they don't know already).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  I did try and look up the product on the B&Q website to see if they had a Q&A section but it seems to have vanished!  I will try again today and then ask next time I am in the store.

Comment: I'd recommend you email the head office - I bet the staff in the shop won't have a clue anyway https://www.diy.com/customer-support/contactus/

Comment: I managed to find the matting on the store sight via an internet search https://www.diy.com/departments/verve-capillary-matting-kit-l-600mm-w-2m/178609_BQ.prd No where to ask Q's about it so I shall take your advice and contact central directly.